# How to show a message about filtering and loading data in Async Pipe Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, async-pipe

I need your help. I have a piece of code with the help of which I get characters from the API and with the help of input, I search for my characters.

Also, I'm trying to show a message in my html that if I didn't find anything during the search for my characters, I saw the message: `no items found`, and when I load data at start and during the search, the message was displayed: `Loading`.

The problem is that my message `No items found` is always displayed. even when the application has just started and the `Loading` message is not displayed at all. Please help me, where is my problem? Thank you very much

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let character of (characters | async)">
  {{ character.name }}
</div>

<div *ngIf="loading">
  Loading...
</div>

<div *ngIf="!response.length && !loading">
  No items found
</div>
```

Typescript

```
public characters: Observable<DifferentCharacter[]>;
public loading: boolean = false;
public response: DifferentCharacter[] = [];

public gettingAndInputCharacters(): void {
const inputSearchItem = localStorage.getItem('inputCharacterValue') || '';

const filterCharacters = (value: string) => {
  return this.charactersService.getAllCharacters(value).pipe(
    map((response) => {
      const characters = response.results.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
      });
      return value ? characters.filter((character: DifferentCharacter) => {
        const name = character.name.trim().toLowerCase();
        const searchInputItem = value.trim().toLowerCase();
        return name.startsWith(searchInputItem) ||
          searchInputItem.split('').every((char: string, index: number) => char === name.charAt(index));
      }) : characters;
    }),
    catchError(() => of([]))
  );
};

this.form.controls['searchCharacterInput'].setValue(inputSearchItem);

this.form.controls['searchCharacterInput'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  this.loading = true;
  localStorage.setItem('inputCharacterValue', value);
  this.characters = filterCharacters(value).pipe(finalize(() => this.loading = false));
  this.characters.subscribe(value => {
    this.response = value
  })
});

  this.characters = filterCharacters(inputSearchItem);
}
```

Comment: Why are you subscribing to value changes inside your function? And where is `gettingAndInputCharacters()` being called?

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid to use the same name for class variable and variable which you use in function. For example response as class variable and in map((response)

This

```
this.characters = filterCharacters(inputSearchItem);
```

looks odd, because earlier you added

```
this.characters = filterCharacters(value).pipe(finalize(() => this.loading = false));
```

and instead of

```
<div *ngIf="!response.length && !loading">
```

use

```
<div *ngIf="!(characters | async)?.length && !loading">
```

and

```
const characters = response.results.sort((a, b)
```

return type {name: string}[]. Not DifferentCharacter[]. It might be a reason of you general issue

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4fre3k?file=src/main.ts

Comment: And why `name` return type should be `string`? I have a DifferentCharacter[] return type, there is an interface structure in which there is a name field. Otherwise, there will be an error. How then to change the code?

Comment: Maybe, I cant see all your code. But response is DifferentCharacter[], What is response.result?

Comment: any result, but also in tap operator i got error

Comment: If you can, share your code by stackblitz. And I'll help you